# Send message to another slack bot

Tags: ruby, slack-api

As a user, you can request an action of a bot from the OS slack app or web page by typing something like `/botname do-something`.

But the same message via chat_postMessage is ignored. Have tried `as_user` with both true and false, as well as `mrkdwn`.

At a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: You need to show some code for context. Show us what you tried.

Comment: @client.web_client.chat_postMessage(text: text.to_s, type: type, as_user: true, mrkdwn: false, channel: channel), with text = '/botname do-something'

Comment: Writing text to the slack channel is not the issue. The issue is the other bot does not interpret what my bot writes.

Comment: Awesome @ErikKalkoken. Am guessing that is the fix, though I get a Slack::Web::Api::Errors::SlackError, "not_allowed_token_type" error when calling @client.web_client.chat_command(channel: '#a-channel', command: '/botname', text: 'do-something').

Comment: It only works with a legacy token.

Comment: If you agree its a duplicate please click on close to confirm. Thanks

Comment: Just verified using a legacy token does work. Thank you @ErikKalkoken!